# How to name and reuse a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following bit of jQuery code that i want to reuse by calling it from other parts of my jQuery code. How would i do that?

```
$(document).ready(function() {              
    $('#share_mention').charcount({
        maxLength: 140,
        preventOverage: false
    });

    $('.countable').bind('update', function(evt, length, remaining) {
        var message = 'id=' + $(evt.target).attr('id') + ', length=' + length + ', remaining=' + remaining;                 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to skin this cat but here is an approach.

```
var yourNameSpace = {};

yourNameSpace.YourFunction = function(){
   $('#share_mention').charcount({
   maxLength: 140,
   preventOverage: false
  });

  $('.countable').bind('update', function(evt, length, remaining) {
  var message = 'id=' + $(evt.target).attr('id') + ', length=' + length + ', remaining=' + remaining;                 
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {   
  yourNameSpace.YourFunction()
});
```

Comment: A slightly shorter way of writing that last line would be `$(document).ready(yourNameSpace.YourFunction);`

Comment: @JoeEnos Yes, provided that is the only thing you want to do upon DOM Ready is that function.

Answer (score 0):

First things first there is no such thing as a jQuery function. It's a javascript function.
The event is implicitly passed to the callback function.

```
function countCats (event) {}

$('.cats').on('click', countCats);
```